# How to hide programmatically timezone and location on a custom user edit profile page in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, users

I need a custom user_profile_form in a page of my drupal site containing a subset of fields provided by the form. I created it and rendered it this way:

```
function mymodule_join_experiment_contr_strict_mode($exp_node, &$form, &$form_state) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');
  global $user;  
  $user = user_load($user->uid);
  $form = drupal_get_form('user_profile_form', $user, 'account', 'strict_mode'); 
  return $form;
}
```

Now in my custom function mymodule_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) i'm doing

```
$form['picture']['#access']=FALSE;
```

in order to hide the field 'picture' and any other field i need to hide. In the form i have two collapsible named 'location' and 'timezone', provided, i think, by 'location' or 'gmap' module. (I didn't realized all this site so i don't really know everything about it.)
Now, even looking at $form i can't see the equivalent for timezone and location. I expected to find something that allowed me to do

```
$form['timezone']['#access']=FALSE;
```

but i cannot find timezone and location... What i am doing wrong?

EDIT: i'm trying to get what is the right way to do it in drupal, before to surrender and use a 'display:none' on css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. I had to use the solution suggested [#35](https://www.drupal.org/node/378622#comment-3569390)

This is the code i used

```
<?php
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'MYNODETYPE_node_form') {
    $form['#after_build'][] = 'MYMODULE_SOMETHING_MEANINGFUL';
  }
}

function MYMODULE_SOMETHING_MEANINGFUL($form_element, &$form_state) {
  //note that I only have one location on this node type
  $form_element['locations']['#access']=FALSE;
  $form_element['timezone']['#access']=FALSE;

  return $form_element;
}
?>
```

I have not quite understood what is going on. An explanation about after_build would be appreciated.

Comment: `very low quality link only` answers are not entertained. 
This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Comment: I corrected the answer to show code. It seemed to me useful to know all the discussion for someone finding this solution.

Comment: Your effort is much appreciated +1

Answer (score 0):

Timezone settings can be disabled on this page admin/config/regional/settings.
And user pictures can be disabled on this page admin/config/people/accounts

Comment: Yes, but i do not want to disable it. I just want to disable it a specific custom page i'm building. It appears for the base of the page is the default user_profile_form, and i do not know how to hide it.